# "Welche" oder "was für eine"?

Tags: standard-german

Why is it *In welcher Stadt wohnen Sie? In einer Großstadt oder in einer Kleinstadt?* and not *In was für einer Stadt wohnen Sie?*

Comment: colloquially, people make no difference between both ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With *in welcher* you ask for the name of the city:

> A: *In welcher* Stadt wohnen Sie?
>   
>   B: Ich wohne in Hamburg.
>
> A: *In which* city do you live?
>   
>   B: I live in Hamburg.

With *in was für einer* you ask for the kind of the city:

> A: *In was für einer* Stadt wohnen Sie?
>   
>   B: In einer Großstadt an der Elbe.
>
> A: *In what kind of* city do you live?
>   
>   B: In a large city at the river Elbe.

Answer (score 3):

It's not.

There is a widespread impression that "Was für ein X" is somehow not "proper" German, and a popular way to avoid it is to switch to "welche". However, this is a bad solution since it changes the meaning: "In welcher Stadt" will be understood as "what city" and not "what *kind of* city".

To say "what kind of city" you'd have to say at least "in welcher *Art* Stadt ... ?"

Comment: but our teacher specially mentioned that it should be welche... i had the same thing in mind what you said